# Error: `false` must be a character vector, not a `factor` object

Tags: r

Error: `false` must be a character vector, not a `factor` object

I want to use this code. It´s a copy paste from a person where it works

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)


isok.60 <- read.csv("~/Documents/StrengthTest/strengthTests.csv")%>%
  filter(!is.na(load), timepoint %in% c("pre", "post"),
         exercise == "isok.60") %>%
     mutate(timepoint = if_else(timepoint == "session1",
                             "pre", timepoint)) %>%
  group_by(subject, timepoint, group, sex) %>%
  summarise(load = mean(load, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = timepoint, 
              values_from = load) %>%
  mutate(change = ((post - pre)/pre) * 100,
         pre.mc = pre - mean(pre))%>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(pre.mc = pre - mean(pre))
```

Comment: Try adding `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you